Expectation of squared quadratic form for multivariate Gaussian
I want to expand the expression $\mathbb{E}[(x^T A x)^2]$ where $A$ is symmetric and I am trying to use the The Matrix Cookbook, but the closest expression I can find is in the "Mean of Quartic Forms" section, using which I get
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[(x^T A x)(x^T A x)] &= \text{tr}(A \mathbb{Cov}[x] (A + A^T) \mathbb{Cov}[x]) \\
&+ \mathbb{E}[x^T](A + A^T)\mathbb{Cov}[x](A + A^T)\mathbb{E}[x] \\
&+ (\text{tr}(A\mathbb{Cov}[x]) + \mathbb{E}[x^T]A\mathbb{E}[x])(\text{tr}(A\mathbb{Cov}[x]) + \mathbb{E}[x^T]A\mathbb{E}[x]) \\
&= 2 \text{tr}(A \mathbb{Cov}[x] A \mathbb{Cov}[x]) \\
&+ 4 \mathbb{E}[x^T]A\mathbb{Cov}[x]A\mathbb{E}[x] \\
&+ \text{tr}(A\mathbb{Cov}[x])^2 + (\mathbb{E}[x^T]A\mathbb{E}[x])^2 + 2 \text{tr}(A\mathbb{Cov}[x])\mathbb{E}[x^T]A\mathbb{E}[x] \text{ (trace is a scalar so can be swapped)} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Is there a simpler expression for this or am I over complicating this?

Use the variance: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/427332/119261.

thanks @StubbornAtom! in that question I do not see the derivation for a more generalized case of $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$. Did you mean that I should take the statement to be proven as it is and use the expression of the variance to derive the expected value of the square by plugging in the statement to be proven for the variance?
